# What is the correct syntax for using "import"?

Tags: intersystems-cache, objectscript

According to [this](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20122/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=ROBJ_class_import) I should be able to have multiple import statements like this:

```
import class1, class2, class3, class4

Class MyApp.MyClass {}
```

The code compiles with one import, but as soon as I place more than one the code fails to compile.

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find it in the documentation, but

```
import (class1, class2, class3, class4)

Class MyApp.MyClass {}
```

seems to work.

Answer (score -1):

[documentation](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20121/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=ROBJ_class_import)
more than one package, you need to take in brackets